# In latest react-native version 'jitsi' meet call buttons are not working in android

Tags: react-native, jitsi, jitsi-meet, lib-jitsi-meet

I have integrated `react-native` `jitsi` `sdk` in my application. In `ios` it is working fine, but in android no buttons are working of meeting conference. Can anyone help me how can I fix this issue ?

> Configurations :

> "react-native": "0.67.2",

> "react-native-jitsi-meet": "^2.2.0",